# Include the value of a variable defined with R in JS javascript code

Tags: javascript, r

How could you include the value of a variable defined with R in a JS script also defined in R?

It should be something like this:

```
maxvaluex <- 150
jsCodeEx <- JS("function() {
 this.xAxis[0].setExtremes(this.dataMin, maxvaluex);
 }")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could substitute into the string like this?

```
maxvaluex <- 150
jscode <- sprintf("function() {
 this.xAxis[0].setExtremes(this.dataMin, %d);
 }", maxvaluex)
jsCodeEx <- JS(jscode)
```

Alternatively, you could use `paste` if you prefer that over `sprintf` or use the **glue**-package if the code is more complicated.